# Flex: Everything goes white when I switch TabNavigator tabs

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3

I've just dropped a `TabNavigator` into my application:

```
    <mx:TabNavigator width="100%" height="100%"
        backgroundColor="#F7F7F7">

        <custom:SomeCustomContainer label="Details" />

        <mx:Canvas label="Reporting" width="100%" height="100%">
        </mx:Canvas>

    </mx:TabNavigator>
```

And when the app first loads, everything seems fine:

> [everything working http://img.skitch.com/20090818-dimqrp3ghd89fp9eftipafajk3.jpg](http://img.skitch.com/20090818-dimqrp3ghd89fp9eftipafajk3.jpg)

Until I click the 'Reporting' tab. Then, sometimes, the the rest of the application (that is, everything outside of the `TabNavigator`) goes white:

> [alt text http://img.skitch.com/20090818-tgud6797qcx18fwxwkik38nrp9.jpg](http://img.skitch.com/20090818-tgud6797qcx18fwxwkik38nrp9.jpg)

Everything seems to go back to normal when Flash is asked to do a redraw (for example, the browser window looses then regains focus).

So, err… Is this normal? Is there some simple way to fix it?

**Edit**: I've tried a variation on Joel's suggestion:

```
// Where 'this' is the main Application
ChangeWatcher.watch(this, ["myTabNavigator", "selectedIndex"], function() {
    invalidateDisplayList()
});
```

And it *mostly* works… Except for a small portion of the `ApplicationControlBar`, which remains white:

[control bar is still white http://img.skitch.com/20090903-fbif9r67jg9wx1rkiwad7sbey6.png](http://img.skitch.com/20090903-fbif9r67jg9wx1rkiwad7sbey6.png)

Comment: I have tried putting my custom component in its own <Canvas>, but that doesn't seem to help.

Comment: It seems like this is a Firefox-specific bug, as I can't reproduce it in Safari.

Comment: What are the dimensions of the custom container? Is it close to or larger than the ~4092px limit in either dimension?

Is this compiled for Flash Player 9 or 10?

Comment: All of the containers are "fairly small" (600px±100, I think), and this is FP9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the historyManagementEnabled property of the TabNavigator to false works for me.

Comment: D'oh! Of course. Why didn't I think of trying that? Anyway, it worked perfectly – thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue with Firefox on Mac. I use PureMVC so my solution wasn't too painful, but I manually dispatch an Event.RESIZE from my root application when I switch tabs. This forces the displayList to refresh and solved the problem.

Comment: Hrm, well, that mostly works… Except for, strangely, a small area in my ApplicationControlBar. See the updated description.

Comment: Instead of `invalidateDisplayList()`, I tried calling `dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.RESIZE))`, but that didn't seem to have any effect… Which is why I tried `invalidateDisplayList()`.

Comment: dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.RESIZE, true)) - to make it bubble? I'm kinda grasping a straws here. Application.application.dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.RESIZE))? This is a crappy bug. I'd like to put it in their bug base, but I can't identify it to do so :/